# Use file with non-ascii letters in filename in \inputminted

Tags: external-files, import, filesystem-access

I want to import some code into a LaTeX-File. The problem is, that in the path some special caracters appear. This still works fine:

```
\inputminted[autogobble,breaklines]{java}{C:/Path/to/my/File.java}
```

But when I change it to this I get the following error:

```
\inputminted[autogobble,breaklines]{java}{D:/Pfad/für/meine/Datei.java}
```

I get the following error:

> File "", line 1 SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape'
> codec can't decode bytes in position 36-37: truncated \uXXXX escape
>
> Error: cannot read infile: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> 'output2.pyg'

When looking into the java-File at these lines it broke the code:

```
> \PYG{k+kd}{protected} \PYG{n}{String}
> \PYG{n}{DATABASE\PYGZus{}URL}\PYG{o}{=}\PYG{l+s}{\PYGZdq{}jdbc:derby://localhost:1337/test;user=user;password=password;create=true\PYGZdq{}}\PYG{o}{;}
```

I've gotten these errors using TeXStudio. I'm still new to LaTeX, I hope I haven't forgotten anything important. In case I did, please let me know.